# Problem understanding 私のにわか景気

Tags: translation

The phrase in question comes from 「カタカナ英語と和製英語：最近の傾向を中心として」からの抜粋. The text describes words in Japanese that appear similar to English words and are written in katakana. I am having trouble understanding this:

> マイブーム(英語{えいご}で言{い}えば「私{わたし}のにわか景気{けいき}」の意{い}。

What specifically does 私のにわか景気 mean? It sounds like *My unexpected condition*. But that seems like a strange translation.

Any help?

Comment: I corrected  the paper title as you seem to have shorten it for no good reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

景気 is not just a condition but a (good) economic condition/climate. にわか is "temporary". にわか景気 refers to a sudden but temporary boom in business/economy, such as the Gold Rush.

私のにわか景気 sounds funny to me, and it's intentionally so. It's for showing how the phrase "my boom" sounds weird to the Western ears. In other words, 私のにわか景気 *should not make sense*.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. That is perhaps why I couldn't understand the Japanese. My mind rejected the interpretation because it didn't make sense, but that was precisely the writer's point. Thanks for clarifying that!

Answer (score -1):

> マイブーム(英語で言えば「私のにわか景気」)

「マイブーム」は何となくわかるが、同時｛どうじ｝に、何となく変｛へん｝な日本語だと思いました。
かっこの中の「私のにわか景気」という意味｛いみ｝を読むと、きっと英語[訳]｛やく｝をした人が「マイブーム」の理解｛りかい｝不足｛ぶそく｝か、英語力か日本語力不足だと思いました。
ＯＰが日本語を懸命｛けんめい｝に勉強｛べんきょう｝している方｛かた｝なら、これでは疑問｛ぎもん｝がでますね。

出典｛しゅってん｝を調｛しら｝べますと[ここ](http://www.ssu.ac.jp/media/sube.pdf)にありました。「カタカナ英語と和製｛わせい｝英語　－最近｛さいきん｝の傾向｛けいこう｝を中心｛ちゅうしん｝として－」という真面目｛まじめ｝な論文｛ろんぶん｝の６ページ目の左側｛ひだりがわ｝にあります。

> マイブーム ((temporary) personal obsession)
>   (英語で言えば｢私のにわか景気｣の意｡

私の直観｛ちょっかん｝では、マイブームの理解が不十分なのと、その英訳が少しズレているのと、更｛さら｝にその日本語訳がかなりズレている感｛かん｝じがします。
３度ズレますと、「マイブーム」のニュアンスはほとんど伝｛つた｝わりませんね。

論文をちゃんと読んでないのでコメントするのは大変｛たいへん｝失礼｛しつれい｝ですが、この論文での意味は、「日本で一般に理解されている「マイブーム」を my boom と英訳しても正しく伝わらないので、「私のにわか景気」という意味で理解し、もし英訳するなら、「私のにわか景気」を丁寧｛ていねい｝に伝えようとするのではなく、(temporary) personal obsession と言いなさい」と善意｛ぜんい｝で解釈｛かいしゃく｝しました。(temporary) personal obsession で少しはニュアンスが伝わるかどうか知りませんが、「私のにわか景気」を一所｛いっしょ｝懸命｛けんめい｝に意訳｛いやく｝してもマイブームの意味を理解するのは無理でしょうね。なぜなら「私のにわか景気」とは何を意味するのか全くわからない日本語ですから。

私が理解している「マイブーム」を[ここ](http://ecafeplus.com/study-english/expressions/addicted-to-something/)で比較的｛ひかくてき｝上手｛じょうず｝に説明しています。

> 「～がマイブームなの！」と言いたい時、英語では「～に夢中｛むちゅう｝になっている」や「～にはまっている」という表現を使います。
>
> 「～にはまっている」の英語表現
>
> Examples
>
> - I’m really into Indian food recently.
>     （最近インド料理にはまってるの。）
> - I’m addicted to sweets in a convenience store!
>     （コンビニスウィーツがマイブームなの。）
> - I’m crazy/nuts about yoga.
>     （ヨガに夢中なの。）

私の結論として、

> 「マイブーム」は、「私のにわか景気」と言う訳｛わけ｝のわからない意味ではありません。
>   日本語として定着｛ていちゃく｝しているというほどではありませんが、「～に夢中｛むちゅう｝になっている」あるいは「～に嵌｛は｝まっている」というような意味で使われる和製｛わせい｝英語です。

---

## EDIT

「マイブーム」に関して更に調べてみました結果を下に記します。

結果として分かったことは、
- 「マイブーム」という言葉は、1990年代に造られたれっきとした和製英語だということです。
- 「カタカナ英語と和製英語：最近の傾向を中心として」と題した論文の著者が日英で異なる意味の和製英語の例として挙げた**マイブーム** を **英語で言えば「私のにわか景気」の意**だと言葉足らずでかつ不明瞭な日本語で解釈したために著者の意図がうまく伝わらず、そのためにＯＰが疑問を持ち、このサイトに質問したのだろうと思いました。
従って、ＯＰがnarutoの回答に対する"My mind rejected the interpretation because it didn't make sense, but that was precisely the writer's point."というコメントを見ますと、前半はあっていると思われますが、後半は著者の意図とは違うと思います。

**後日追加**：論文の著者の意図を正しく反映させるためには、「マイブーム」を「3) 日英で意味の異なる和製英語」という副題の中の例として挙げるのではなく、「英語としては意味をなさない和製英語」というような副題の例として挙げ、必要なら、英語ではどのような（奇妙な）意味で理解されるか、あるいは全く意味をなさないかを補足すればよいのではないでしょうか。
**EDIT in EDIT**
*In order to correctly reflect the intention of the author of the thesis I would not propose that "my boom" is cited as an example in the subtitle "3) 日英で意味の異なる和製英語　3. English Japanese English with different meanings in Japanese and English" but I propose to list it as an example in the subtitle like "英語としては意味をなさない和製英語　Japanese English not meaningful as English" to the author. Furthermore, if necessary, supplementation should be added as to what kind of (strange, curious, odd or funny) meaning is understood in English in the example, or not at all*.

Wikipediaの「[みうらじゅん](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BF%E3%81%86%E3%82%89%E3%81%98%E3%82%85%E3%82%93)」によると、
「マイブーム」は、1997年に新語・流行語大賞のトップテンになり、かつ、2006年に「死語大全」にも選ばれている不思議な言葉です。日本の漫画家、イラストレータの「みうらじゅん」さんが創造した和製英語です。

新語・流行語大賞を受賞した言葉は、一般的にマスコミが多用する例はあるもののマスコミ外で流行したとは言い難いものがほとんどであり、その年限りの一過性に終わり死語と化すことも多い。その中で、「マイブーム」はマスコミ外でも広く使われており、受賞後も廃れることなく使用され続け、遂には2008年1月に発売された『広辞苑第六版』にも掲載されている珍しい例といえます。

「死語大全」にも選ばれた流行語ですから、最初の私のAnswerで日本語として定着しているというほどでないと私が判断したのも不思議ではないと思います。

#### 意味は、

- 「自分の中だけで はやっている物や出来事」（上記「みうらじゅん」の記事）
- 「個人的に夢中になっていること（個人的な流行）」（日本語俗語辞典）
- 「《(和)my＋boom》自分の中での流行。自分が現在集めているもの、興味をもっているものごとをいう」（goo国語辞典、ディジタル大辞典）
- 「他の人がどう思っていようと、自分の中では流行している、すなわち自分が今はまっているもの（こと）」（知恵袋）
- 「一九八〇年代以降の「豊かさ」の実現と個人の関心の多様化により、「先端」こそがカッコいいという生活美学に基づく「先端」の追求は次第に失速し、各自の価値観や感性に基づく等身大の「個性」が追求されるようになってきた。それは、**ひとりひとりの「こだわり」が確立**しつつあることを意味しており、「多様化」=「すみわけ化」を前提とした上での消費こそが、九〇年代消費社会の本質といえるのである。そんな「すみわけ」状況を象徴することばが「マイブーム」である。これは、イラストレーターのみうらじゅんの命名したものであり、多くの人を巻き込む社会的流行=「マスブーム」と違い、**ひとりひとりが自分の関心のある趣味やテーマを追い求める状況を指している**。いってみれば、**それは個人の嗜好そのものなのだが、あえてそれを「ブーム」という言葉に置き換えることで、世間に影響を受けない個人の自発的意志を強調しているのである**。」（とっさの日本語便利帳の解説）（ゴシック体の部分はmackygooが強調した）

#### 「マイブームは死語か」

- 「今のところ、それに代わる便利な言葉が見当たりませんし、自分がハマッてることを表すのには誰もがわかる最適な言葉だと思いますよ！ むしろ『ハマッてる』って言葉の方が古臭くて死後のような気がしますが… ちなみに最近のマイブームはダーツです」（知恵袋）
- 「マイブームって普通に使いますよ。死語ではありません（キッパリ）おいらのマイブームは喜多方ラーメンです」（知恵袋）
- 「全然死語じゃないと思いますし、普通に使ってますよ。むしろ和製英語として生き続けるような気がします」（知恵袋）

[image]

Comment: あのですね・・（なるとさんが言ってることと同じなんですけど、）「私のにわか景気」って書いた著者は、『「マイブーム」とは「私のにわか景気」って意味ですよ』って言ってるんじゃなくて、『「マイブーム」って、そのまま英語にしてmy boomって英語話者に言ってしまうと、「私のにわか景気」って意味にしか聞こえなくって、変ですよ、意味が全然通じないですよ』って言ってるんです・・・

Comment: ＠ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ: その通りです。違うのは、ブックカバー、デノミ等々は英語に日本語のカタカナ語と違う意味がちゃんとあるのですが、my booｍだけは、英語としては意味をなさない英語なのでここれ例を挙げるのがサブタイトルから判断してふさわしくないのです。だからＯＰがなんじゃこれと思うのは正しいのですが、論文の作者はそんな意図をもってこのサブタイトル内に置いたとは思いませんが、論文の作者は変な英語だと思って欲しいから書いたとナルトさんもＯＰも思っているようなので違いますと申し上げております。立派な論文ですが、この度の質問のロジックは作者の掲載場所のミスだけが起因です。

Comment: @mackygoo 筆者は「英語で直訳するとまともな意味を成さない」というカテゴリを敢えて別に設けていないのですから、自動的に「ガソリンスタンド＝燃料立て」とか「スキンシップ＝皮膚度合」のようなほぼチンプンカンプンな例であってもここに含まれると考えているのでしょう。それが良い分類かどうかはさておき、この部分の筆者の意図を理解することは難しい話ではないと思いますが。

Comment: @naruto: OPの別の質問にあったように「日本語と英語では意味が微妙に大きく異なる和製英語である」範疇での例ですし、また、マイブーム以外の他の例から判断しても、「チンプンカンプンな例」を入れたかったとは思えないので、貴兄の判断は別に、著者のちょっとした選択ミスでいいんじゃないですか。