# What does 様 mean here?

Tags: meaning

> 傲慢{ごうまん}を語{かた}る男{おとこ}が、それを実現{じつげん}していく様{さま}を見{み}るのは心地{ここち}よいものだ。

What could it be ? I don't have the slightest idea, though I would translate the whole sentence as :

> "Seeing a proud man achieving this is quite pleasant."

Comment: How do you propose to read 様 here? Please provide a (partial) translation, otherwise this question will be closed.

Comment: I don't have any proposition as I'm not familiar with this 様 at all. The only one I know is the one showing respect (ｘさま) but it can't be this one.

Comment: Maybe you could check a dictionary if you don't know other readings...

Comment: I've already done that, but I don't think there is any stem or noun before 様 so I really don't know which is why I'm asking. Or perhaps is it used as a noun by itself, meaning "thing" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does exactly does さま mean in dictionary definitions?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9915/what-does-exactly-does-%e3%81%95%e3%81%be-mean-in-dictionary-definitions)

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43853/9831

Comment: Would this dictionary entry be of help? -> http://jisho.org/word/様-1Noun `3. state; situation; appearance​ フラフラと[歩]{ある}き[回]{まわ}る[様]{さま}は、あまりにデンジャラスだ。The way she dizzily moves around is far too dangerous.`

Comment: I see, I see. Thus, it would mean "Watching 'the way' an arrogant man realizes it is quite pleasant." Am I correct in my understanding ?

Comment: @Ushiromiya そうですね、そんな感じだと思います。Btw, 傲慢を語る男 literally means "A man who talks about arrogance"... and I don't think it means "An arrogant man". He is not an arrogant man *yet*; he is now in the process of realizing arrogance (=それを実現していく)... i.e. in the process of becoming an arrogant man... no?

Comment: @Ushiromiya In fact, we say rarely 傲慢を語る. Probably you want to say 大口をたたく (to boast, to brag, to exaggerate), don't you?

Comment: ^ ここを読めば →　http://weeaboo.org/Umineko/jscript5.txt　文脈わかりますけど、「大口をたたく」って意味ではないようです

Comment: Thank you for your link, but I can't find the part because of its quantity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explaining the sentence 今になってもまだ実現していないさま](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43853/explaining-the-sentence-%e4%bb%8a%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82%e3%81%be%e3%81%a0%e5%ae%9f%e7%8f%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%95%e3%81%be)

Answer (score 4):

It's さま and basically means 'appearance'.

Answer (score 3):

This 様 is read さま, and it basically means *(observable) situation*, *appearance* or *state*. It's similar to plain old 様子, but さま is less colloquial and always used with a relative clause or この/あの/etc (i.e., 様子を見る is okay but さまを見る is not). In addition, さま often (but not always) has a negative connotation and is preferred in dismissive sentences like this one. [ざま](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%A7%98) (or [ざまあ](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%A7%98%E3%81%82%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8D), see the dakuten) is a derivative word of this and is always derogatory. So その様子 is neutral, そのさま is sometimes derogatory, そのざま is always derogatory.

> 傲慢を語る男が、それを実現していく様を見るのは心地よいものだ。

Here さま is interchangeable with 様子, and it literally means "It's pleasant to see  the situation where a man who talks about arrogance is realizing it (=arrogance)."

It needs a little more context, but this sentence probably refers to the ironical situation where a man who always says "don't be arrogant" is becoming arrogant.

---

**EDIT:** @chocolate posted the [source text](http://weeaboo.org/Umineko/jscript5.txt) in the comment section. The original text is as follows:

> 「如何にも。妾こそが、右代宮家顧問錬金術師、黄金の魔女ベアトリーチェである。……妾は奔放にして自由！　誰の命令も聞かぬ。」
>   「それを、世界でたった一人。私だけが支配した。……だからこそ、右代宮家の当主たりえるのだ。」
>   「ふっ。その傲慢さこそが右代宮家当主の資格だと言うか。」
>   「傲慢とは即ち、自信であり勇気である。そしてそれに見合う力を得ようとする、飽くなき向上心の現われである。…だからこそ、私はお前を支配した。」
>   「**………傲慢を語る男が、それを実現していく様を見るのは心地よいものだ。** 不言実行は強運なる者の言い訳に過ぎぬ。…真の王者は持たぬ物さえも語る。そしてその傲慢を確かに実現して見せるのだ。……妾を支配できる者には、その王者の傲慢が必要だ。」
>   「わかるか、夏妃よ。真の王者は、あらゆる苦難を恐れぬ。必ず乗り越えられると公言する。その算段がなくともだ。だから弱者は希望を持つ。集い、崇め、協力を誓う。そこに力が生まれ、有言は実行されるのだ。それを心に刻め。」

So my interpretation in my original answer turned out to be wrong. (That's why we always need contexts ) What I can tell from this is that these characters are exchanging a fairly rhetorical, euphemistic, tricky conversation. 傲慢 ("arrogance") is normally a very negative word; it's far from "pride" or "confidence", which are of course normally positive. But they are somehow treating 傲慢 as if it were an indispensable trait of a leader. In this conversation, "realization of arrogance" is considered as the the symbol of the power of a lord, and everyone in the conversation is talking as if they believed in such an idea that "a true governor must be arrogant."

So the gist of what the sentence is saying is "A man who believes in the value of arrogance is actually behaving arrogantly. I understand it and I'm glad to see that."

Answer (score 2):

様{さま} has the meaning like 様子{ようす}, 状態, 姿. I think English words like state and scene are close to it.

So それを実現していく様 would mean " a scene the man is realizing it".

Answer (score 1):

I'd verbalize it as さま as you normally read the sentence. But the character itself can also sometimes be read as よう.

If it was written artistically I would write furigana like this:

> それを実現していく[様]{すがた}を見るのは

Answer (score -2):

> "Seeing a proud man achieving this is quite pleasant."

I think your interpretation for the sentence with (1) is correct.

> (1) 傲慢を語る男が、それを実現していく様を見るのは心地よいものだ。

If you add furigana to the given sentecnce it will be as (2).

> (2) 傲慢{ごうまん}を語{かた}る男{おとこ}が、それを実現{じつげん}していく **様{さま}** を見{みる}るのは心地{ここち}よいものだ。

Though the Jisho.org defines **様{さま}** as "state; situation; appearance​" [here](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%A7%98), we don't use it for the state or appearance of an ordinary person. If you use it to an ordinary person it is rude to him/her, because 様｛さま｝ has a nuance of despising or looking down on the person who is described with this word.

様｛さま｝ is suitable for the use as follows.

> - ふらふらと歩{ある}いているあの酔{よ}っ払{ぱら}いの **様{さま}** はみっともなくて見{み}ていられないね。
> - *You cannot keep watching the drunk man who is pacing with a swaying, right?*.

傲慢{ごうまん}を語{かた}る男{おとこ} in (1) or (2) could be interpreted like "*a man talking about arrogance*" in English, so 様{さま} is used safely in this sentence because we usually hate such an arrogant person.

If we describe the state of an ordinary person we use 様子｛ようす｝ instead of 様｛さま｝ as follows.

> - 彼{かれ}の **様子{ようす}** は普段｛ふだん｝とちょっと違{ちが}うと思{おも}わないかい。
> - *Don't you think the state of him is somewhat different from usual?*

Judging from the nuance that 様｛さま｝ has, the sentence with (1) posted by the questioner having the meaning as follows in English is not logically natural.

> (1) *It is pleasant to see a man who talks about arrogance realizes it (or his dream).*.

I would rewrite it into (3).

> - (3) 傲慢{ごうまん}を語{かた}る男{おとこ}が、それを実現｛じつげん｝できない様{さま}を見{み}るのは心地{ここち}よいものだ。
> - (3) *It is pleasant to see a man who talks about arrogance cannot realize it (or his dream)*.

---

## EDIT

私の最初の回答に2件down-voteがありました。up-voteはゼロです。

私の最初の回答で、質問にあった文に使われている「様」は「さま」と発音し、"state; situation; appearance" すなわち「様子や状態」のような意味があると回答した上で、敢えて次の２つの情報を付け加えました。

１つ目は、この「様{さま}」は、質問で提示されたような「傲慢な人」に使う場合は問題ないが、普通の人に使うと「失礼になる」から駄目である。もし、普通の人に使う時には「様子」という表現にするようにという内容です。

２つ目は、与えられた「傲慢を語る男が、それを実現していく様{さま}を見るのは心地よいものだ。」という文は、文脈的に見ておかしい（論理的でない）、もし例文を書き換えるなら、「傲慢を語る男が、それを実現できない様{さま}を見るのは心地よいものだ。」と（揶揄{やゆ}する文脈に）するべきではないかと提案しました。

down-voteの２件がいずれの意味で「駄目」と言ったのかはコメントがないので定かではありませんが、私は、１つ目の情報に対してだろうと判断しこのEDITを行います。

「様」には上記の「さま」と発音する意味とは別に、「ざまあみろ」「あのざまは」というように「ざま」と発音して、ある人をあざけるあるいはさげすむ時の表現としての意味があることは承知しております。

down-voteした人の判断に対する私の推察は、私が「様{ざま}」の意味なりニュアンスを「様{さま}」が持っていると勘違いして上記の１つ目の情報を付け加えたと理解し、「あなたの理解は間違いですよ。様{さま}は様{ざま}のようなニュアンスを持っていませんよ。だから普通の人に使っても問題なしですよ」と言うご指導だと思っております。

実際には、私は何ら勘違いすることなく、「様{さま}」は迂闊{うかつ}に普通の人に対して使ってはいけないと思っております。裏打ちできる情報はないかと調べましたが現在のところ見つかっておりません。しかし、私の感性から判断すると日本語を勉強している人に対して何某{なにがし}かの追加説明があってしかるべきテーマだと判断し、説明を試みることにします。

国語辞典ではどうなっているか押さえておきます。

三省堂大辞林で「様{さま}」と「様{ざま}」とは次のように説明されております。

> **さま** 【様・方▽】（▽表外読み）
> （名詞）
> ① 物事の様子や状態。ありさま。 「彼女の寂しげな様｛さま｝」 「蝶の群れ飛ぶ様｛さま｝」 「様｛さま｝変わり」
>
> **ざま** 【様▽・態▽】
> 〔「さま（様）」の転〕
> （名詞）
> 様子や格好などを、ののしったりあざけったりしていう語。 「その様｛ざま｝はなんだ」

確かに「様{さま}」には「様{ざま}」のような意味はありません。

「様{さま}」の用例にある「蝶の群れ飛ぶ様{さま}」 と「様{さま}変わり」は全く問題ありません。
「彼女の寂しげな様{さま}」。これも問題ないと思います。但し、小説か何か叙述文の中で使われるとしたらです。
次に登場人物を卑近な人に置き換えて考えてみましょう。「町内会長の寂しげな様{さま}に会計担当の者が声を掛けた」、「息子の寂しげな様{さま}が気になる母親」。やはり小説の中ではありそうな表現です。しかし、小説以外で普段こんな表現を使いますか？私は、このような言葉をそばで聞いたらこそばゆいとでも言うのでしょうか、いたたまれない気持ちになります。
ところが、「町内会長」や「息子」の例文で、「様{さま}」を「様子」に置き換えるとどうでしょう。「町内課長の寂しげな様子」や「息子の寂しげな様子」は、聞きなれた普通の表現になりませんか。こそばゆさは少し解消します。本当は、「寂しげな様子」より「寂しそうな様子」の方がもっと普通ですね。ということは、「寂しげな様{さま}」は、口語（会話文）では余り使われない表現なのだと思います。

一方、例えば、「あいつの偉そうな様{さま}を見ているとムカついてくる」は立派な口語（会話文）であり、「あいつの偉そうな**様子**を見ているとムカついてくる」とも言い換えられます。どちらかというと、「あいつの偉そうな様{さま}を見ているとムカついてくる」の方が「偉そうな様子」よりしっくりくるような気が私はします。
それは、「様{ざま}」の影響かなと思って「様{さま}」を「様{ざま}」と言い換えてみますが、「あいつの偉そうな様{ざま}を見ているとムカついてくる」とは言いません。「様{ざま}見ろ！」と字面{じづら}は似ていますが、「...偉そうな様{ざま}...」とは言いません。

次に、誰かが、「町内会長の偉そうな様{さま}を見ているとムカついてくる」と普段の会話で言うと当然喧嘩になりますが、「町内会長の堂々とした様{さま}を見ていると...」と誉めるつもりで言っても、「様{さま}」をわざわざ遣う必要がどこにあるのかと言葉遣いに対する違和感がありますので、「あいつ会長に恨みでもあるのかな」と勘ぐられる可能性なきにしもあらずです。普通に言うなら、「町内会長の堂々とした**様子**を見ていると...」が穏当な表現だと思います。「息子の嬉しそうな様{さま}を見ていると」にも同様の違和感があります。

結果、「様｛さま｝」は「彼女」「町内会長」「息子」の例文で「様子」に置き換え可能ですが、逆は必ずしも問題なしで可能とは言えないことになります。すなわち、普通の人に対しては、「様{さま}」と「様子」とは相互に置き換え可能ではありません。
ところが、「あいつ」を使った例文では、「様子」と「様{さま}」とは相互に置き換え可能です。
蔑{さげす}んでよい人とそうでない人（＝普通の人）とで、「様{さま}」が安全に使えるかどうかに確かな差があります。

「様{さま}」と「様子」との置き換え可能性に関して、もう一つ別の条件があります。

「彼女の寂しげな様{さま}」と「蝶の群れ飛ぶ様{さま}」は、「彼女の寂しげな様子」と「蝶の群れ飛ぶ様子」と言い換えられます。しかし、「彼女の様子」 「蝶の様子」とは言えても、「彼女の様{さま}」 「蝶の様{さま}」とは言いません。

「様{さま}」は、上記の国語辞典で「物事の様子や状態。ありさま。」とありますが、単なる「様子」ではなく、「〇〇〇である様子」と言う意味合いになるのだろうと推察できます。
従って、仮に「様子」が「様{さま}」に置き換えられると判断される場合、またその逆に「様{さま}」が「様子」に置き換えられると判断される場合でも、「〇〇〇である様子」と「〇〇〇である様{さま}」という一つ大きな単位が対象となって置き換えられると判断し置き換えを実施する必要があります。

２番目の用例である「蝶の群れ飛ぶ様{さま}」 に関しては、「様子」でも「様{さま}」でもほとんど条件はなく相互に置き換え可能です。
「蝶」は「人」ではないので、対人関係のような相手に対する感情の働く余地が生じない、従って、辞書の定義通りの意味で「様{さま}」を使っても問題は生じないのでしょう。

国語辞典の用例にあった最後の「様｛さま｝変わり」に関しては、「**様子**変わり」と言い換えられませんので、これは、決まり文句の一部としての「様{さま}」なのだと思います。

以上見ますと、国語辞典の３つの用例の各々の「様{さま}」が全て用途的には違う扱いを受けることが分かります。

結論として、
（１）「様{さま}」は、人以外の動植物（主に動物）の様子を表すときには、辞書の定義通りの意味で使える。
（２）「様{さま}」は、叙述文（／書き言葉）において人の様子を表すときには、辞書の定義通りの意味で使える。
（３）「様{さま}」は、口語（／会話文）において人の様子を表すときには、蔑{さげす}んでよい相手に対しては辞書の定義通りの意味で使えるが、普通の人に対しては、違和感を与えたり相手の感情を傷つける可能性があるので使用を避ける。もし、辞書の定義通りの意味で使いたい場合は、「様子」で置き換える。
（４）「様{さま}」は、問題なく「様子」で置き換えられる。
（５）「様子」を「様{さま}」で置き換えられる場合はあるが、前提として、置き換える前の文が、「〇〇〇である様子」あるいは同等の表現である必要があり、かつ、置き換え対象の文が（１）～（３）のいずれの条件に相当するか確認の上、（１）～（３）で定める条件を守る必要がある。

結論を見ると何だか契約書みたいになってしまいましたが、ことほど左様に、「様{さま}」は、国語辞典通りの意味で単純には使えないと思います。

契約書のような配慮がいやであるなら、"state; situation; appearance"の意味として、「様{さま}」ではなく「様子」、場合によっては「状態」と表現することが賢明だと思います。

最後に、上記国語辞典を含め、辞書における「様{さま}」の定義には何らかの（あるいはどのようなときに使えるかという）説明文の追加が必要であると思っております。

Comment: voteしてないので推測ですが、文脈知らないのに「文脈的に見て論理的でない」と言って恣意的に原文を変えたのは流石にまずいのでは。じっさい、文脈がわかってみれば普通に意味が通る文ですし。

Comment: @naruto:>「じっさい、文脈がわかってみれば普‌​通に意味が通る文ですし。」　ＯＰが提示した原文は日本語としてはそのままではとても受け入れ難いのですが、narutoさんの最初の回答を見て、貴兄も大変苦労して考えたのだろうなと感心して読んでいましたのに...。それなのになぜEDITしたのですか。作者は作者で正しいですが、作者でもない貴兄が作者の立場になる必要は全くないと思います。今後とも自分の日本語に対する感性を信じて、どう理解するのが正しいのかを、日本語学習者に向き合って、正しい日本語を素直に伝えていきましょう。

Comment: 「OPが提示した原文は日本語としてはそ‌​のままではとても受け入れ難い」といまだに言ってる時点で、それがdownvoteの原‌​因じゃないかと指摘しているのですが。[この‌](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52292/5010)​ときも[この](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52159/5010)ときも[この](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53580/5010)ときもそうでしたけど‌​、 mackygooさんはプロが書いたごく普通の文に不条理なケチを付けて自爆するパターンが多い気がします。「文脈がないと意図をつかみづらい」ことはみんな理解しており、だから原文を探したりしていたのですが、この文そのものは普通です。「この文そのものが不合理だ」‌と言っている人はあなただけです。

Comment: @naruto:（１）傲慢を語る男が、それを実現していく 様｛さま｝ を見るのは心地よいものである。　（２）傲慢を語る男が、それを実現していく 様{さま} を見るのは **見ものである** 。　（３）傲慢を語る男が、 **失敗する 様{さま} を見るのは** 心地よいものである。　質問者が日本語を学んでいる外国人の場合、「様」の読み方を別にすると、（１）をどう理解して良いか分からないと尋ねた場合、あり得る答えは、確かに、提示された文を含む文脈を提示してくださいと要求する手もありますが、最初の答えは、次のようなものではないでしょうか。　「あなたが（１）をなんだか変だな、あるいは理解に苦しむというのは日本語の理解が正しい証拠です。　きっと（２）や（３）なら、よく理解できるでしょう。普通の日本人はあなたと同じように考えます。」　一般には、この質問に対する回答はこれで終わるはずです。　傲慢を語る男を肯定視するのではなく、客体化してこれに冷ややかに対峙するというのが、この日本語文に対して抱く通常の感覚です。【つづく】

Comment: 【つづき】　ところが、この質問に対する回答やコメントを見ておりますと違うようです。　さて、そのような人には、次のような設問があっているのでしょうね。　「（１）の文が正しいとする。この文を自然に受け入れられる先行する文を500字以内で創作してください。文は複数に分かれていてもかまいません。」　どこかの入社試験にありそうです。　しかし、この設問は、このサイトの範囲を超えております。　これ以上のコメントは不要です。　自爆はしておりませんのでご安心を。